# Change image onclick (specific patern)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, onclick

So, I'm new to javascript and I got this assignment:

> "Find a figure with the number 1 and name it "**one.jpg**" on a page.
>   Change the figure (figure 2) to "**two.jpg**" when it is clicked.
>   Change after another click to "three.jpg" then back to "**one.jpg**"

However, I cannot seem to find a solution for this. All examples I found use buttons.

Comment: Its good to try to do your homework that way you learn from your mistakes

Comment: You should try to show us what you have already tried. I want to help, but I don't think you will get better unless you try it first.

Comment: If you have an example that uses a button then that will be similar to what you need. You can bind a `click` handler to any HTML element, so just do that with your image element instead of a button. (Incidentally, allowing clicks on images to do things is bad from an accessibility point of view, because keyboard-only users who can't use a mouse can't access that functionality - better to wrap the image in an anchor element and do the processing from the anchor's clicks, because that works with mouse *or* keyboard.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is I think what you want to happen.

```
<img src="one.jpg" id="imageid" onclick="img_clicked()">
<script>
    var clicks = 1;
    function img_clicked() {
        clicks ++;
        switch(clicks) {
            case 1: document.getElementById("imageid").src="one.jpg"; break;
            case 2: document.getElementById("imageid").src="two.jpg"; break;
            case 3: document.getElementById("imageid").src="three.jpg"; clicks = 0; break;
        }           
    }
</script>
</script>
```